# Matlab polyfit for a region of data

Tags: matlab, graph, new-operator

I have a set of data I need to generate two linear best fit lines for (1st order `polyfit`) but I don't know how to specify which region each line should fit data to. I need one line in the region between minimum x value and 0 and the other one in the region 0.25 < x.

Also, in the second region, there are two clear areas of data, one above the other, and I need the best fit line to be fitted only to the lower one.

I am a complete novice at Matlab so any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: The graph I need the best fit lines on]

```
%load data, force and velocity
load ('exp_6_Force');
load ('exp_6_Velocity');

% Give a name to the title bar.
set(gcf,'name','Experiment 6 velocity','numbertitle','off')

%set variables to x and y 
x = Force; 
y = Velocity;

%plot the graph
plot(x,y);

%add grid and legend
grid on;
legend ('Velocity');

%add labes and title
xlabel ('Force');
ylabel ('Velcoity');

% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);

%find coordinates of y min point
[value,index1] = min(y);
yminxcoor = x(index1);
yminycoor = y(index1);
```

Comment: See logical indexing here (https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Comment: For regions, do you mean x_min < x < 0 for region 1 and 0 < x < 0.25 for region 2?

Comment: @BanghuaZhao yes for the first region, no for the second. For the second region, I am only interested in the data that is tightly grouped and x>0.25. That should make sense with the image.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [logical index](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) to get the `x` and `y` data for the two regions:

For region 1:

```
x_region1 = (x<0).*x
y_region1 = (x<0).*y
```

For region 2:

```
x_region2 = (x>0.25).*x
y_region2 = (x>0.25).*y
```

Then you can `polyfit` in these regions

For region 1:

```
p_region1 = polyfit(x_region1, y_region1, 1)
```

For region 2:

```
p_region2 = polyfit(x_region2, y_region2, 1)
```